# List metrics for all repositories on my GitHub Enterprise

Tags: git, api, github

We are trying to get GitHub Enterprise usage details. I need to list all repositories and get metrics like commits per day, Language etc for each repository. I referred https://developer.github.com/v3/ . I see that there is way to list organization (Max limit 100) and then list all repos per organization. I could get metrics per repository. However is there any way to list metrics for all repositories.

Comment: How about looping over the repos?

Comment: Looping over repos will increase API calls to GitHub Server and it can cause performance issues. Also again there is pagination limit for API result. So this will complicate the things. Hence I am looking to get all data in one API call.

Comment: Sure, the API is paginated and that's it. You cannot "unpage" the request or exceed the limit of 100 results per page. You at least have to loop of the pages of that result.

Comment: @Vampire I guess thats the only option. Thanks for help. Cheers